# How can I get these orphaned parts to snap to their bones and join the animation?

Tags: animation, vertex-groups

I've got this figure that I imported as an FBX:

[image]

For reasons unknown, the figure's right hand and part of his right elbow didn't have vertex groups assigned when I extracted them--those groups are simply missing, but the bones are there, and those bones are being animated properly.  I can establish the correct vertex groups for the elbow and parts of the hand by naming the new vertex groups the same as the corresponding bones, but I'm not sure how to get them to "snap" to their respective bones and start behaving correctly.

For instance, I've done exactly this with the elbow part, which is the bottom section within that blue circle in my pic above.  The corresponding bone is named "bn_Titan_Ark_extra21", so that's what I've named the vertex group.  I was kind of expecting something would happen when I switched back from Edit to Object mode, but that part of the mesh just stayed where it was while the rest of the figure is animating properly.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Adding this image for reference to comments below:
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/46c6lbjb06kh6cd/Ark.blend/file

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to look for.

Make sure the vertex assignment to vertex groups is clean and the vertices only belong to the correspondig bones´ groups.
Weight painting mode is a quick visual aid for this and in Edit mode you can check weights in the N panel.
[image]
In this image we see the vertices are weighted to more than one bone.

For all this, in Mesh Edit Mode, Menu Vertex>Vertex Groups>Remove from All is a handy tool. Then assign to whatever group you have or create.

If you have to create a new vertex group for bone binding, make sure the bone has the Deform check to On in the Bone Settings Panel (Right side panel).

And to the mesh to be in its place when animating, edit its vertices translating and rotating them so the piece is where it should be in the robot. Use whatever snapping and placement tools, this can be tricky specially if there is no starting T pose as in this case.
[image]
In the image: Quick eyeballing placement, but animation worked (just to check).

In the provided file animation needs some cleaning and tweaking, but it falls into a different issue IMHO.

EDIT:
Check the parts you want to bind have a correct bone to be bind to.
In the last provided file example, there are no right side equivalent for the left wrist and hand bones. If your character is symmetric, add the bones by symmetrizing existing ones or create them before binding.

Comment: So, to follow up on that, I made an interesting discovery.  I used a different extractor, and pulled the robot out using just his first animation (the original file has two animations, back to back). When I load up the figure in Blender, he loads in robot mode, with the problem parts out of position, as you've already seen.  But when I select the mesh and go to Edit mode, the figure shifts into its vehicle mode and the problem parts snap into their proper places.  I'm trying to figure out what this means, and if I can use it to properly align the problem parts.  Pic added to original post.

Comment: Here's a new blend file for what I mentioned above:
https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/xs1ofwp7sz2hw7u/Ark_2.blend/file

Comment: On further review, I see that what is happening is that the right elbow and right hand are in the proper position for when the figure is in its space shuttle mode.

Comment: The same procedure  applies here, the good thing is that being in place you can Skip the part of precise placement. Just make sure Deform is ON in the bone settings for the Vertex bindig to work.

Comment: Every time I check the "Deform" option, the mesh portion in question jumps to another part of the scene.

Comment: I´ve checked your second file, there are no right side symmetric equivalent for the left arm bones from the wrist so i symmetrized them (after proper renaming) and following the upper procedure, assigned the vertices to the _r bones (easier since they are properly placed in Edit Mode/shuttle form). It works for me assuming the animation is symmetrical. I can expand the anser to cover this.